# How long will my session last?

Tags: php, session, timeout

Can someone please tell me how long my session will last from the data below? - I'm not sure which one tells me

```
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off Off
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php/session    /var/lib/php/session
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In general you can say [*session.gc_maxlifetime*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) specifies the maximum lifetime since the last change of your session data (*not* the last time `session_start` was called!). But PHP’s session handling is a little bit more complicated.

Because the session data is removed by a garbage collector that is only called by [`session_start`](http://php.net/session_start) with a probability of [*session.gc_probability*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) devided by [*session.gc_divisor*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor). The default values are 1 and 100, so the garbage collector is only started in only 1% of all `session_start` calls. That means even if the the session is already timed out in theory (the session data had been changed more than *session.gc_maxlifetime* seconds ago), the session data can be used longer than that.

Because of that fact I recommend you to implement your own session timeout mechanism. See [my answer to *How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960) for more details.

Comment: How does session.cache_expire interact with this?

Comment: `session.cache_expire` does only influence HTTP caching of the server response but doesn't have any influence on the session expiration.

Comment: Oh, I see, cache_expire works together with cache_limiter. PHP's documentation is very unclear about that. 
I couldn't decypher a single word of what is documented here: http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php until I read this: http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php
Thanks @Gumbo

Comment: @matteo Unfortunately, there are many cases in which the manual is rather unclear.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in the Debian/Ubuntu distro, by default PHP disables its session garbage collection mechanism. Instead, it runs a cron job every half hour (see the script /etc/cron.d/php5) to purge session files in the /var/lib/php5/ directory. (source: https://www.appnovation.com/node/2564)

Comment: @greg as of debian 10 buster, using PHP version 7.3, the cron is now located at `/etc/cron.d/php` and the session files `/var/lib/php`. the source's [link](https://www.appnovation.com/blog/session-garbage-collection-php) has also moved

Answer (score 21):

This is the one. The session will last for 1440 seconds (24 minutes).

```
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
```

Comment: 24 minutes is a weird default and it's also a rather short time. I have a theory about this: The person that set this default thought it was expressed in minutes. 1440 minutes just happens to be exactly one day, which is an actually reasonable default. But at this point nobody dares to fix it.

Answer (score 8):

[If `session.cookie_lifetime` is 0, the session cookie lives until the browser is quit.](http://no.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)

**EDIT**: Others have mentioned the `session.gc_maxlifetime` setting. When session garbage collection occurs, the garbage collector will delete any session data that has not been accessed in longer than `session.gc_maxlifetime` seconds. To set the time-to-live for the session cookie, call [`session_set_cookie_params()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) or define the `session.cookie_lifetime` PHP setting. If this setting is greater than  `session.gc_maxlifetime`, you should increase `session.gc_maxlifetime` to a value greater than or equal to the cookie lifetime to ensure that your sessions won't expire.

Comment: Thanks, when I close the browser and open up the page again, I still see the same sessionId?

Comment: If your browser was still running, then, yes. The session cookie only expires when the browser application quits.

Comment: The cookie yes, but the session itself will expire after 24 minutes without any activity even if you keep the browser open.

Comment: That's correct (and something I forgot to mention). I've edited my answer with an explanation of these settings.

Comment: It’s not the access time but the moodification time.

Answer (score 8):

You're searching for gc_maxlifetime, see http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime for a description.

Your session will last 1440 seconds which is 24 minutes (default).