# How is PHP $_SESSION timed out?

Tags: php, session

What exactly happened?

I don't know the undergoing so I can't understand how `session_set_save_handler()` actually works.

Comment: This question, as worded, makes no sense.  Are you asking how PHP actually times out sessions?  How long the default timeout is?  Or, as the body of the question implies, are you asking how the save-session handlers work?

As worded, I have no idea what relationship you're seeing between session expiration and the save handlers you can attach to sessions.

Comment: @delfuego,I'm asking all you mentioned.

Comment: Then you need to spend a little time in the PHP Sessions reference:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

That should answer all the questions you have.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516266 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237

Answer (score 1):

Session timeout is declared in php.ini
If you can edit the php.ini, change:
    session.gc_maxlifetime 72000
If you cannot edit the php.ini, put this in your .htaccess file:
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 72000
That should allow the session to "live" for at least 20 hours (72,000 seconds), even without any activity.

If that doesn't work, and you're on a shared host, it could be that the host empties the session directory on a periodic basis. Do your sessions all die after a pre-determined amount of time? (i.e. 10 mins?) If that's the case, you could move your sessions into the database using a custom session handler.

Comment: The session timeout happens when no request,I wonder how can something be done when there is no request?

Comment: I'm still confused how what you're asking about session timeouts has *anything* to do with what you're asking about session save-handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Most people would think *session.gc_maxlifetime* defines the session’s lifetime.

But that’s not quite correct. *session.gc_maxlifetime* is only the lifetime after that the garbage collector of PHP’s session implementation assumes the session to be expired. But the garbage collector is only called with a chance of 1% (default settings). So it’s very probable that the session might be used though it is already expired.

The best would be if you implement a session timeout mechanism on your own and register it with [`session_set_save_handler`](http://php.net/session_set_save_handler). It should test if the current session is still valid and invalidate it immediately if it’s expired.

See [my response to *How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960) for further details.