# Why my session expires sooner than the time I have set?

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP sessions timing out to quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476538/php-sessions-timing-out-to-quickly)

In my .htaccess file I have set

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 14400
```

i.e. for 4 hours

if I verify using `echo ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');` I get 14400. But still my session expires in, say, less than 2 hours.

What do you think is going wrong here? any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No our own Windows server hosting multiple websites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Some distributions (Debian, at least) have a cronjob that removes old sessions a regular interval. This cronjob gets the [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://php.net/session.gc_maxlifetime) setting from the system's php.ini and thus ignore your vhost config.

  Solutions:

  - Set `session.gc_maxlifetime` in the system's php.int (e.g. `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`)
  - Move the sessions for this vhost to a separate directory (set [`session.save_path`](http://php.net/session.save_path))
- An other probable cause is that the session cookie expire before session itself. Make sure that the [`session.cookie_lifetime`](http://php.net/session.cookie_lifetime) variable is at least equal to `session.gc_maxlifetime` (or `0`).

Comment: If I set separate directory using sesssion.save_path would the old/expired session files be cleaned as usual by the system? Or I need to tell it somehow? Thanks

Comment: Yes, they will be cleaned by PHP at a regular interval (defined by the other session.gc_ settings)

Comment: I've just checked session.cookie_lifetime value and it is 0 (zero) Do you think it could be causing it? Its great that files be cleaned auto. Thanks.

Comment: `0` means that the cookie won't expire until you close the browser

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Debian machine, you might have an automatically installed cronjob, that deletes sessions. Look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654310/cleanup-php-session-files) and specifically Paul Dixon's answer.