# session ended though lifetime didn't end in php

Tags: php, session, lifetime

I'm using this code to set a login session from this answer

[issue with session lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197826/session-timeout-issue-in-php#answer-15197968)

```
$lifetime=604800;
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime);
```

checking the resources tab from inspect element the session cookie should end on 2015-10-20

[image]

But I was signed out after closing the webpage in an hour and when I print the session I get " Undefined index: SESSION_NAME". So how to solve this problem and set the correct session lifetime to work?