# php sessions expire too fast - session.gc_maxlifetime

Tags: php, session

I set session.gc_maxlifetime to 43200, which should be 12 hours, but my sessions still expire very fast. I want it to be at LEAST 12 hours

i created a php_info.php file so i can see how things are configured

- session.auto_start    Off Off
- session.bug_compat_42 On  On
- session.bug_compat_warn   On  On
- session.cache_expire  180 180
- session.cache_limiter nocache nocache
- session.cookie_domain no value    no value
- session.cookie_httponly   Off Off
- session.cookie_lifetime   0   0
- session.cookie_path   /   /
- session.cookie_secure Off Off
- session.entropy_file  no value    no value
- session.entropy_length    0   0
- session.gc_divisor    100 100
- session.gc_maxlifetime    43200   43200
- session.gc_probability    1   1
- session.hash_bits_per_character   4   4
- session.hash_function 0   0
- session.name  PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
- session.referer_check no value    no value
- session.save_handler  files   files
- session.save_path no value    no value
- session.serialize_handler php php
- session.use_cookies   On  On
- session.use_only_cookies  Off Off
- session.use_trans_sid 0   0

Comment: Do you have any other sites or applications on the server? How are you seeing expiration? gc_maxlifetime wont affect the cookie though. Only cleanup on the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP sessions timing out too quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476538/php-sessions-timing-out-too-quickly)