# Extend PHP session lifetime

Tags: php, session

I have this code in my htaccess file in my root directory.

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 86400
```

But PHP sessions don't last longer than a few hours.

Comment: run phpinfo() and post what session.save_path is

Comment: and are you on a shared web server?

Comment: Yes it's a shared web server @DrewP84

Comment: I will have a look now at the php info

Comment: also whats it say for session.gc_maxlifetime and session.cookie_lifetime in phpinfo();

Comment: session.save_path /tmp /tmp

Comment: session.gc_maxlifetime 86400 1440

Comment: session.cookie_lifetime 86400 0

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP sessions timing out too quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476538/php-sessions-timing-out-too-quickly)

Answer (score 6):

**On a shared web server**, when the `session.save_path` is the common default location, the shortest `session.gc_maxlifetime` of all the accounts is what gets used to delete the old session data files.

**You need to set `session.save_path` to be to a private folder within your account's folder tree in order to get your session settings to apply to just your session data files.**

Create a folder of your own and set the session.save_path to match that folder. You must set the `session.save_path` before every `session_start()`. Setting it globally in a local php.ini file would be the best way to set it.

Comment: How do I set it in the php.ini file?

Comment: See this reference: http://jesin.tk/using-custom-php-ini-files-on-shared-hosting/

Comment: and this one: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Comment: Have you got any example for the php.ini file. That first link is just showing how to add it above every session_start();

Comment: with phpinfo() look at the row called `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` ... then make a copy of php.ini and place it in the root of your web server. now you can make edits to it

Comment: You can also try `ini_set('session.save_path', '/path/to/session');` if you have full access to the server (not shared hosting)