# Session expires even if I'm working, session lifetime, Ajax and Symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, session

I have configured my application for close session on timeout if user do nothing during 10 minutes period. At `config.yml` I have this:

```
session:
    handler_id:  ~
    cookie_lifetime: 600 # 10 minutes
    gc_maxlifetime: 600 # 10 minutes
    gc_probability: 1
    gc_divisor: 1
```

I do a Ajax call every one minute to check if session will be close to expire or doesn't and this is what I check:

```
public function isLoggedInAction(Request $request)
{
    $response = array();
    $response['authenticated'] = FALSE;
    $status = 200;
    $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
    if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        $response['authenticated'] = TRUE;
    }

    return new JsonResponse($response, $status ?: 200);
}
```

For some *unknow* reason is not working and every 10 minutes session is closed whether I'm working with page or doesn't, why? I'm missing something?

**Edit 1** Tried new values, still not working:

```
session:
    handler_id:  ~
    cookie_lifetime: 1800
    gc_maxlifetime: 600
    gc_probability: 1
    gc_divisor: 100
```

While I was working on the page, performing Ajax calls and some other tasks the session was closed so is not working. The only value that *apparently* works for me til now is set `cookie_lifetime: 86400 #1 day` which is crazy to me!

**Edit 2** After **@acontell** suggestion for fix the VM time and date I'm trying with this new values (10 minutes takes too long so I've changed to 3):

```
session:
    handler_id:  ~
    cookie_lifetime: 1800
    gc_maxlifetime: 180 # session will expire after 3 minutes of inactivity
    gc_probability: 1
    gc_divisor: 100
```

And also I fixed the date/time on the VM by enabling `ntpd` service and now date is just fine:

```
[root@webvm var]# date
 Sun Feb  1 18:35:17 VET 2015
```

But after 5 minutes (function call was executed 5 times) session still alive. This is how I call the function `isLoggedInAction()` from Javascript side:

```
$.post(Routing.generate('isLoggedIn',{}),{},'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    if( data.authenticated ){
        var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
            $.post(Routing.generate('isLoggedIn',{}),{},'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                if( !data.authenticated ){
                    window.clearInterval(timer);
                    $.growl({
                        message: 'La sesión ha expirado por inactividad, debe <a href=""><b>iniciar seción</b></a> nuevamente.'
                    }, {
                        type: "danger",
                        allow_dismiss: false,
                        timer: 10000,
                        animate: {
                            enter: 'animated fadeInDown',
                            exit: 'animated fadeOutUp'
                        },
                        onHide: function(){
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).fail(function(){});
        },60000);
    }
}).fail(function(){});
```

See the image below:

[image]

**Test 3**

After say all was working fine I did the latest and definitive test: open the application and leave untouched during all the night (almost 8 hours) and surprise it never closes the session. As image below show see how many request the page does and see how session still alive, why?

[image]

Ajax call is made every: 10.5 minutes

```
$.post(Routing.generate('isLoggedIn',{}),{},'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    if( data.authenticated ){
        var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
            $.post(Routing.generate('isLoggedIn',{}),{},'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                if( !data.authenticated ){
                    window.clearInterval(timer);
                    $.growl({
                        message: 'La sesión ha expirado por inactividad, debe <a href=""><b>iniciar seción</b></a> nuevamente.'
                    }, {
                        type: "danger",
                        allow_dismiss: false,
                        timer: 10000,
                        animate: {
                            enter: 'animated fadeInDown',
                            exit: 'animated fadeOutUp'
                        },
                        onHide: function(){
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).fail(function(){});
        }, 210000);
    }
}).fail(function(){});
```

Settings say that session should expire passed: 10 minutes.

```
session:
    handler_id:  ~
    cookie_lifetime: 630000
    gc_maxlifetime: 630000 # session will expire after 10 minutes of inactivity 
    gc_probability: 1
    gc_divisor: 100
```

Time at server is fine:

```
[root@webvm sencamer.dev]# date
Mon Feb  2 07:26:53 VET 2015
```

What else should I check?

**Test 5**

Ok, I'm still doing test because this has not a good behavior. So, this is what I've do for this test:

- Open the application and start working on it
- At some moment stop working and leave the the application made the Ajax call to check whether session still alive or not. (session still alive see image below)
- After that first call I continue working on the application as *image 2* shows but surprise session ends and the application gets close.

Why? What is causing that behavior? Is that right based on my parameters?

*This image shows the first and only call to the function*

[image]

*After the call was made I continue working but session gets closed*

[image]

Comment: have you added session_start() in the top of your php script ? have you restarted your Apache server after updating your yml file ?

Comment: @HalayemAnis `session_start()`? That applies here? I don't think so since Symfony does the job perhaps I'm mistaken but is what I understand unti now

Comment: watch out your gc_probability and gc_divisor. You have both to one and that means that the probability that the garbage collector (GC) process is started on every session initialization is gc_probability / gc_divisor = 1/1 = 1.

Comment: @acontell I'm not following you, what is wrong with that?

Comment: it means that there's a 100% chance that the GC process will start on each [request](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session). It could be related to the problem you mention because it throws an error. Try setting gc_divisor to 100 and see if it helps

Comment: @acontell so, what is the idea? What I should do in order to fix the issue? Change one value? To less or more? Change both?

Comment: Try changing gc_divisor to 100 and if we're lucky it might solve the problem :)

Comment: @acontell still not working man, can you give me another idea?

Comment: @ReynierPM are you using a Virtual Machine? Is the date of the server of your VM set properly? I mean, does it have the correct date? The resulting session cookie will be stamped with an expiry time of time() + cookie_lifetime where the time is taken from the server. It could be possible that, if the server had a bad date, the cookie would expire inmediately. Imagine: server date 2015-01-31, your browser 2015-02-01. Server sends cookie that expires on 2015-01-31 at 11pm, your browser receives a cookie that would expire inmediately.

Comment: @acontell it's outdated `Fri Jan 30 08:06:07 VET 2015` let me fix this and see if that solves the issue

Comment: that makes sense :) even the date, if you have a look at it, it makes sense that one day of expiry time worked

Comment: please, let me know if it works and I could prepare an answer so that if it happens to someone else they know what to do :)

Comment: @acontell still not working further details on __Edit 2__ at main post

Comment: @ReynierPM check your configuration, you set `cookie_lifetime: 1800` which means 30 minutes

Comment: @acontell and should be? which value should be there in order to kill session at 3 (for testing) or 10 (development & production) minutes?

Comment: it's meassured in seconds, so you should use 180 for 3 minutes and 600 for ten minutes. So `cookie_lifetime: 180` for testing purposes and `cookie_lifetime: 600` for production

Comment: we can carry on in my answer, here it's getting messy

Comment: So, have you solved it?

Comment: @sectus No, I didn't but I move on from this project so I can't test anymore. I am starting a new one and I am pretty sure I will need this so maybe I will come back with the same. Are you working on this? Do you have any solution?

Comment: @ReynierPM, sadly, no.

Comment: @sectus are you actively working on something like this?

Comment: @ReynierPM , I blame this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476538/php-sessions-timing-out-too-quickly , but it need to be tested either.

Comment: @ReynierPM, wrong, symfony uses its own local path. It seems that session garbage collector uses creation time of session instead of update time.

Comment: @sectus so, what's the solution? Create our own session timeout? I have read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476538/php-sessions-timing-out-too-quickly, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516266/how-long-will-my-session-last/1516284 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960 and still not get a proper solution for the issue, did you test any of them? If so let me know the results on your side

Comment: @ReynierPM , stupid, stupid me. ... :^ ) But I have found the solution. It's very easy. Do not specify `cookie_lifetime`. After first visit you got cookie with expiration time which does not update anymore.

Comment: @ReynierPM, so not setting `cookie_lifetime` helped you? does it solve your issue?

Comment: Hi @OlegAbrazhaev that whas a while ago and I don't remember if I found a solution or which was the solution, I can only say give it a try and let us know if it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, watch out your `gc_probability` and `gc_divisor`. If both are set to one, that means that the probability that the garbage collector (GC) process is started on every session initialization is `gc_probability / gc_divisor = 1/1 = 1` (100%).

You could leave it to the defaults or give it a higher number in order to reduce the chance of the GC being called.

For instance:

```
session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
        cookie_lifetime: 600 # Ten minutes
        gc_probability: 1
        gc_divisor: 10000
```

Also, if you're using a Virtual Machine, check the date of your server, the resulting session cookie will be stamped with an expiry time of `time() + cookie_lifetime` where the time is taken from the server.

It could be possible that, if the server had a bad date, the cookie would expire inmediately. Imagine: server date `2015-01-31`, your browser `2015-02-01`. Server sends cookie that expires on `2015-01-31` at 11pm, your browser receives a cookie with an expiration date that has already passed.

Comment: Still not working, I've changed the values, cleared the cache but PHP side still say `authenticated` on Ajax has made five calls already. The worst part here is that sometimes I'm just working and session just expire and that is killing my brain since I can't find where the problem is. Is there any chance to compare values between cookie and PHP session? Something that gives a better clue?

Comment: Are you sure that you changed `cookie_lifetime`? in your post you have the variable `gc_maxlifetime` = 180 and `cookie_lifetime` = 1800. In theory, it should work. If no request is made from that session in 3 minutes, the session should expire.

Comment: Yes, the values are `cookie_lifetime: 180 gc_maxlifetime: 180` and none request has been made other than the Ajax request for check if session still alive or doesn't

Comment: How often are you making that AJAX request? I mean, you have to make one AJAX request, wait 3 minutes (let's say 3:30) and make another one. If you make one request every minute, the session won't expire

Comment: Ummm that could be the issue, the only doubt I have is how to make the next call on `3:30` minute?

Comment: No worries, in the timer that makes the AJAX call just change the 60000 to, let's say 210000 (three minutes and a half). First AJAX call should succeed, but the one within the timer shouldn't

Comment: Excellent, for now it works if I have any problem or question I'll comeback thanks for your time

Comment: Well, is not working man, I don't know why and what else to do at this point, any other clue?

Comment: @ReynierPM Your settings are wrong. First off, your cookie lifetime is 630000 seconds which translates in more than a week (not 10 minutes of inactivity but more than a week). It is completely natural that the session didn't expire. Secondly, you are making ajax calls every 210000 ms which translates in 3.5 minutes (not 10.5 minutes as you suggest in your post).

Comment: Waits a minute, that values are expressed on miliseconds or seconds? That's a confusion for me

Comment: The timer of the setInterval in javascript is expressed in milliseconds so 210000 = 3.5 minutes. `cookie_lifetime` is expressed in seconds so 630000 = more than a week.

Comment: So, right values are: for `setInterval` `630000` miliseconds which translate into 10.5 minutes and for `cookie_lifetime` and `gc_maxlifetime` `630` seconds which translate in 10.5 minutes, those are right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct :) set the `cookie_lifetime` to 600 to make the session expire after 10 minutes of inactivity

Comment: sorry man to bother you again but see __Test 5__ edit something is wrong with this, can you help me around this new behavior? It's right?

Comment: @ReynierPM it's difficult to track an error without knowing exactly what you've been doing and this can become endless. From my experience, Symfony manages sessions pretty well, it sometimes throws you out of sessions because of the GC process, but you can either get rid of it (`gc_probability: 0`, never tried this approach though) or lower its chance to get called (what I usually do, `gc_divisor: 10000`). I think the rest is ok and should work. I can't help you further, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

try with these parameters :

```
gc_probability: 0
gc_divisor    : 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but this is tricky question and it helped me building something so here is how you can build it in symfony 4+

It is explained in the doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html but still tricky, so there is a sample configuration

**parameters.yaml**

```
parameters:
    session_lifetime: 1800 # 30 minutes
```

**framework.yaml**

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: 'session.handler.native_file'
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
        use_cookies: true
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax
        cookie_lifetime: 0 # cookie is destroyed when the browser is close
        gc_divisor: 100
        gc_probability: 100 # garbage collector process on each request (100/100)
        gc_maxlifetime: '%session_lifetime%' # session is destroyed after lifetime of user idle
```

**twig.yaml**

```
twig:
     globals:
         session_lifetime: '%session_lifetime%' # so you can use the variable in any template
```

**AbstractController**

```
// extend this one in the controllers
class AbstractController extends SymfonyAbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/is-logged-in", name="is_logged_in")
     */
    public function isLoggedIn(Security $security)
    {
        $response = ['authenticated' => false];
        if ($security->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            $response['authenticated'] = true;
        }

        return new JsonResponse($response);
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
checkLoggedIn = function (isLoggedInUrl, loginUrl, sessionLifeTime) {
    
    let timer = window.setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: isLoggedInUrl,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data['authenticated'] === true) {
                        console.log('checkLoggedIn OK');
                    } else {
                        window.clearInterval(timer);
                        // you can use any message system you want here instead of Toasts
                        $(document).Toasts('create', {
                            title: 'Warning',
                            body: 'Session expired, <a href="' + loginUrl + '">please reconnect</a>',
                            class: 'bg-danger',
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
        },
        (sessionLifeTime + 60) * 1000 // the login check will be sent 60 sec after session supposed expiration
    );
}
```

**your_base_template.html.twig**

```
<script>
    checkLoggedIn("{{ path('is_logged_in') }}", "{{ path('security_login') }}", {{ session_lifetime }});
</script>
```