# Handle $_SESSION through pages in a php site

Tags: php, session

I googled to solve my question but any site explains my problem in a different way so I feel very confused!

I realized a php site in this way.

***index.php:***

In this page I get username and passw from login form and after checked if the user really exist I'll save them first in a variable and after in session.

```
$_SESSION['user']=$user;
$_SESSION['psw']=$psw;
```

Now I would show this page ONLY if the user is logged, so I would make some like this:

***first_page.php:***

```
   <?

   if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" && isset($_SESSION['psw']) && isset($_SESSION['psw'])!=""{

// show page site
}
else
  // go to index.php

?>
```

and insert this block if-else in any pages of the site.

It is correct this procedure?
I need to introduce `session_start();` in any page or just in index.php?
How long time `$_SESSION['user']` and `$_SESSION['psw']` (expires)?

Since the site needs `$_SESSION['user']` for many features, I need to be sure that when a user navigate the site those session variables are setted.

Thanks for your support, I feel very confused on it.

Comment: `$_Session` is an outright syntax error. It's a superglobal. Read up on it http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php and compare their syntax with what you have.

Comment: never store sensitive information in `$_SESSION`

Comment: oh so now you went and edited that. did you start the session?

Comment: *"I need to introduce session_start(); in any page or just in index.php?"* - why not start with the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php - it speaks for itself.

Comment: I'm asking this because I notices that, if I comment the string: session_start(); in other pages I didn't receive any error and I could navigate site the same...

Comment: *"I didn't receive any error"* - you didn't get an error because your system's either not setup to catch those, or you didn't use error reporting. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Rossco which is a good practice to save user connection (to navigate the site)  without using $_SESSION variables?

Comment: thanks  @Fred -ii-, I discovered this function right now.

Comment: @andre3wap why are you trying to set OP's code back to `$_Session` in an edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11406182 are you mad? Edit rejected. Please don't do that.

Comment: and @Alexei you're no better, approving the edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11406182 don't you know what a superglobal is? or php for that matter.

Comment: ok, I give up. let the edit go, I'm done here. *ciao tutti!!*

Comment: @andre3wap Let's call it a *"Communication Breakdown"* then. Great Zeppelin song though ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store a password in a session, without changing the session handler data in a session is stored as plain text outside of the web root. This means anyone that has access to the system can read session data.

The method of knowing if a valid login occured is:
`$sql = "select id where username = 'username' and password = 'hashedpassword'"`

If an id is returned it means the user successfully logged in and store that ID in a session. Then validate if the session continues if the ID is set.
Keep in mind that after raising privileges it is recommend to change the session id as well, that can be done with `session_regenerate_id()` this to add protection for session fixation attacks.

At the beginning of each script when trying to read data from a session use `session_start()` and `session_destroy()` to remove all data stored in that session (usually a logout)

Comment: Thanks for you support @Xorifelse! What do you think about this in any page of my site? <?

   if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" && isset($_SESSION['psw']) && isset($_SESSION['psw'])!=""{

// show page site
}
else
  // go to index.php

?> It is correct to do this?

Comment: It is not, `isset($varname)` returns true if the variable is `not null` you cannot compare it with a string `isset($_SESSION['user'])!=""` as this will always fail.

Comment: Well, so you mean to check only this: if( isset($_SESSION['id'])) is true show the page, else return to index. Without saving username and password. Right?

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly. Just `if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){/* code here */}` would suffice. However you can also store a username in a session if you so prefer. However the ID is usefull for database table joins.

Comment: Thanks! Another thing that I answered is: when this $_SESSION['iduser'] expires. If I log in in my site and I don't click on logout button, how many hours later this variable will be destroyed?

Comment: That can be set in the [php.ini](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476538/php-sessions-timing-out-too-quickly)

Comment: Could this solution better? if ((isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) && $_SESSION['iduser']!=NULL) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage  }
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp  And put this code at the top of any page of the site?  (took from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Comment: Essentially, it's the same method I personally use, it offers for more flexible code. You could also add-in cookie code so that the user can set to set his own no activity time at login. But its all about what would suffice your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You must add `session_start()` in every single page where you use `$_SESSION`. It expires when you leave the site.

Comment: I'm asking this because I notices that, if I comment the string: session_start(); in other pages I didn't receive any error and I could navigate site the same... without errors. About the second answer, when you say: It's expires when you leave the site, you mean log off? thanks!

Comment: *"It expires when you leave the site."* - You mean "when you close the browser" or when the session time/session life runs out or has been destroyed.

Comment: @FrancescoL. I've answered that in 2 ways ^

Comment: Perfect, I would know this properly: "when the session time/session life runs out". How can I determinate this time? If I log the site and (without click on logout button) I re-enter in the site 2 hours later, those session variables has been destroyed?

Comment: @FrancescoL. that's up to the answerer to take it from here. seeing they already got an upvote for their answer, I'd only be a 3rd wheel here ;-)

Comment: seems we're not getting much *"after-sales service"* here, huh?

Comment: Sorry @Fred-ii-... I don't know what is happening...  you wrote:
 
andre3wap,  Alexei,  downvote... I dont undestand nothing. I was just asking some to perform my site :(

Comment: @FrancescoL. andre3wap is wanting to edit your question's code in a suggested edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11406182 where it should be refused. One person approved it, and I have no idea why. I and someone else refused it. It clearly would change your code/question in a bad way. Not too "molto bene" ;-)

Comment: Ok, Now I understand. So thanks. Anyway I noticed that some php code has been removed from my post by someone! maybe is for this reason that I got -3 votes.

Comment: @FrancescoL. just goes to show how some think they're doing good, but do more harm than anything. *c'è troppo confusione per io*. -  *sigh*. Gotta go, *ciao*

Comment: thanks @Fred-ii- for your reply and support. According to you is a good practice to do so in any page of my php site?     <?

   if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" && isset($_SESSION['psw']) && isset($_SESSION['psw'])!=""{

// show page site
}
else
  // go to index.php

?>

Answer (score 0):

If I introduce at the top of any page the following script, could be a good solution? Or there's something wrong?

```
if ((isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) || $_SESSION['iduser']==NULL) { 

// last request was more than 30 minutes ago 
session_unset(); 
session_destroy(); // destroy session data in storage 
echo "<script>location.href='index.php'</script>"; //redirect the user to index page
} 

$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp 
/* Code for the rest of my page HTML*/
```

(took from here: [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes))