# apache php server weird logout issue

Tags: php, mysql, apache, centos

we have recently moved PHP application on new server,but we are facing weird session out issue on new server, the `session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400` in php.ini but the application goes logout in between site surfing, app was working fine on old server, so we are suspecting issue in sever configuration, this is [phpinfo url](http://www.inspectandcloud.com/phpinfo.php)

can you please advise if we are missing anything in configuration.

Thank you

Comment: Are you Tried this link [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476538/php-sessions-timing-out-too-quickly)

Comment: @KarthiVenture, the link is looking useful thanks