# PHP session expired after 24 mins even user is active and working

Tags: php, session

webUser.php

```
//create/start session                
session_start();
$sessionId = session_id();
$_SESSION["sessionid"] = $sessionId;
```

Home.php

```
session_start();

$currentsessionId = session_id();

if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionid'])||($_SESSION['sessionid'] !=$currentsessionId))
{
    $message = 'Restricted to access! please login';
    header("location: login.php?error=$message");
}
```

Comment: Hi, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476538/

Answer (score 0):

The default session expiry time is 1440 seconds (24 mins)

Reference: [PHP Manual: Session configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)

To increase the lifetime in runtime, use the following command:

```
ini_set(’session.gc_maxlifetime’, 2*60*60); // Change the session timeout value to 2 hours
```

Comment: i dont want to increase the session max time because it works fine at inactive user but the issue is that it also works for active user who working and session gets timeout after 24 minutes