# php session expires randomly after a few minutes

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have a login page/system which has worked correctly for years, leaving the user logged in until he/she either closes the browser window or logs out manually. But lately (starting yesterday) after only a few minutes of inactivity the session cookie/s seems to expire, causing the user to be logged out automatically.

This happens on different browsers and different operating systems, the PHP version is 5.6.29, which has been changed recently (before it was 5.5 and even 5.3).

I create and refresh the session on every page with `session_start()`. The login script first checks user name and PW and also gets some other user data from the database. These other data are first saved in variables and then written into session variables like

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $name;
$_SESSION['usertype'] = $type;
```

The successful login state is saved like this:

```
$_SESSION['login'] = "ok";
```

On the other pages I check the login state like this:

```
session_start();
if(($_SESSION['login'] != "ok") OR ($_SESSION['usertype'] != "xxx")) {
 header("Location: ../login.php"); /* redirects to login page if conditions are not true */
 exit;
 }
```

The login works, and logged-in users can proceed to other pages as long as the do it more or less in constant succession, but **if someone waits a few minutes** before proceding (i.e. without any acitivity), he/she is **logged out** (i.e. redirected to the login page when trying to open another page).

To make it extra-nasty, half of the time it just works as expected, also after half an hour...

Any help would be very much appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

Adding `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600');` and `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 3600); didn't help. I removed it again.

After that I had a look in the error logs and found this:

> ap_pass_brigade failed with error 103: Software caused connection
>   abort

(problem is, I don't have access to the server settings - this is on a shared webspace...)

Comment: If you have installed a new PHP, then check the `php.ini` file. The default session timout is probably the default, where your old system would have had it upped to a larger time

Answer (score 2):

You can see the php configuration (php.ini) by phpinfo();

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Check the session.gc_maxlifetime values first then if you need to set it see the following ways.

You can set it with .htaccess file if you don't have permission for edit the php.ini file.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value session.cookie_lifetime 3600
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 3600
</IfModule>
```

Even you can set it by [ini_set();](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.ini-set.php)

```
<?php
     ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
```

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476538/php-sessions-timing-out-too-quickly

Comment: you should use the default session values in php.ini. also try to clear the browser cookies and check for errors in the error log file for the web site. you can also check if the folder that stores the session data has the correct permissions

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested: The session didn't actually expire, but the session variables disappeared (and reappeared again randomly).

This is discussed in a follow-up question I posted here:

[php $_SESSION variables disappear and reappear randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41490713/5641669)

Answer (score 0):

You must have changed the `session.name` from default `PHPSESSID` to something else. Keep its default value `session.name = PHPSESSID`. Everything will be OK.

It's a PHP bug.