# Code Igniter cookies behaving differently in local dev env than on live site

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I see $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;

However, when I inspect my cookie, I can see on the live site it expires after 1 year and it's constantly updating. And on my local dev env, I inspect the cookie and see it expires after 10 min and stays static.

Any one have any insight?

This is code that I inherited and I'm not familiar with code igniter, so please let me know if there is any additional information you'd need in order to help.

Comment: There's a bunch of setting that effect session lifetime. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476538/php-sessions-timing-out-too-quickly). Some setting must be different on the server.

Comment: Try storing session on database by creating ci_session table