# session timeout forever cakephp

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x ... i am using auth component ... the problem write now is that the session automatically expires after some minutes.. i mean  if the user does nothing then   CakePHP  logs them out after some period...i want to make the session time forever unless he click the logout button ..i dont know how to to do this .. any help would be greatly appreciated

Here's my config code:

```
 Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php'
));
```

Comment: Have you *ever* tried reading the book before asking here? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#session-configuration

Comment: well i have seen dere ..they are explicitly writing the time period ... which i dont want .. e.g 'timeout' => 4320 //3 days

Comment: How many minutes is "some minutes" - how long is "some period"? Is your question how to change the timeout, or that users are being logged out after e.g. 2 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using the default php sessions and they are configured (in `php.ini`) to expire sooner than you want to. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516266/how-long-will-my-session-last/1516284).

If you want your logins to live forever it's probably better to use cookie based login. See [this plugin](https://github.com/ceeram/Authenticate) for instance.