# Session timeout after 1 day

Tags: php, session

I have a homepage the user logins in too with this php code:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $username= $_SESSION['username'];

    if($_SESSION['username'] == "")
    {
        header("Location: http://new_system/");
    }

    require "connection.php";

    $result= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $firstname = $row[0];
    $lastname= $row[1];
    $email = $row[2];
    $birthday = $row[4];
    $gender = $row[5];
    $path = $row[8];


    ?>
```

I tried adding this

```
$_SESSION["timeout"] = time()+ (0*1*0*0);
```

So it logs out after a day but it didn't work, can anyone tell me why. I put it under the if statement for session

Comment: `SESSIONS` only last for 24 minutes (1440 seconds), you have to change settings in your `PHP.ini` file to get a longer `SESSION` timeout, look at this page for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

Comment: Mine kept me logged in for 4 days now, I just wanted to make it one day instead of four. @Jek

Comment: If you look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1516283/5782416 you can see that if you have other settings in your `PHP.ini`, it lasts till your browser is closed, is that what happened?

Comment: I guess I didnt close my browser, but I just noticed that I have to logout for my session to be destroyed, is there no code I could put to make it one day only?

Comment: There is as the answers have provided, was just making sure you knew before you asked **:')**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Code.

```html
 $inactive = 60*60*24;
if( !isset($_SESSION['timeout']) )
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time() + $inactive; 

$session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];

if($session_life > $inactive)
{  session_destroy(); header("Location:index.php");     }

$_SESSION['timeout']=time();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION["timeout"] = time()+ (0*1*0*0);
```

Is incorrect 
Multiplying any number by zero (0) is zero (0)

Change to something like this 
For 10 minutes 
10 * 60

For 24 hrs ( a day) 
24 * 60 * 60

```
$_SESSION["timeout"] = time()+ (24 * 60 * 60);
```

You can echo it out to see the difference

Answer (score 0):

You have also too set the cookie timeout. For the cookie default is the window session, when you close the browser, the cookie times out.  the session_id is saved in the cookie, when the cookie expires, the session also expires.