# PHP Session data disappears after 3 minutes

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am having issues with session data disappearing.  While I won't say it's not code related, the conditions seem that way.  After logging in, I can see the session data stored in the session file in the session data store.  After 3 minutes, without doing anything with the browser, the data in the session file disappears.  I'm using CentOS 6.8 and PHP 5.6.0.

```
session_start();    
if(($_REQUEST['login_btn'] || $_REQUEST['username'] || $_REQUEST['password']) && !$_SESSION['auth']) {
    if(!$_REQUEST['username'] && !$_REQUEST['username']) {
        header("Location: /?msg=bp");
        exit();
    }
    if($_SESSION['auth']!=1)
    {
        if(!$conn)
            $conn=mysql_conn();
        $sql="select pid,CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) as pname,email1,password FROM people WHERE email1 = '".addslashes(str_replace(" ","",trim($_REQUEST['username'])))."'";
        $res=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        if(mysql_num_rows($res)<1) {
            header("Location: /?msg=bp");
            exit();
        }
        else {
            $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
            $user=$row['email1'];
            $pass=$row['password'];
            if($pass != $_REQUEST['password']){
                header("Location: /?msg=bp");
            }
            else {
                $_SESSION['pid'] = $row['pid'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $user;
                $_SESSION['pname'] = $row['pname'];
                $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant php.ini settings:

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "/data/session"
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 0
session.cache_limiter = nocache
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this on a shared host?

Comment: No, it's a dedicated server.

Comment: Run phpinfo(); and see if gc_maxlifetime is still set to 0.

Comment: session.gc_maxlifetime = 0 according to phpinfo().

Comment: Any crons doing any cleanup on that save path?

Comment: Not yet.  I changed gc_maxlifetime to zero to try to solve this, with the plan to add a cron job for garbage collection.

Comment: If you try a number greater than 3 minutes does it obey?

Comment: I set gc_maxlifetime to 5 minutes (300), but still have no session data in the session file after 3 minutes.  Sometimes the file is gone, other times just empty.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure what else to check. Absolutely tied to this install? This might be good reading material: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516266/how-long-will-my-session-last/1516284

Comment: Thanks for trying.  I'd read that link already, which led me to change gc_maxlifetime, although the default 1440 is longer than the 3 minutes I'm experiencing.  Yes, tied to this install.  I have an identical server with the same php.ini (copied and diffed), same php.conf, and same httpd.conf that is not experiencing the issue.  Versions are the same.  I'm stumped, but the users are frustrated with timing out every 3 minutes.

Comment: You could install auditd to possibly track down what is deleting them. Have you tried a different save_path?

Comment: Changing back to default of /var/lib/php/session yields the same 3 minute lifespan.