# If a user leaves/closes a php script, does it automatically end the session?

Tags: php, security

I have a script that calls a function that starts the session with `session_start();` command.
If the user closes the page early, will the session variables remain stored and waste memory? Or do I have to run `session_destroy()` at some point?
I'm worried that multiple users would force to server to store a lot of extra data.

Comment: This answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516266/how-long-will-my-session-last

Comment: If the session is created and is not timeout session values will exist !

Comment: dont worry php knows how to take care of itself.

Comment: garbage collection will deal with this.