# Keep PHP session active after removing the URL parameter

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to get the value of an URL parameter and save it to a JS variable using PHP session.

My URL: `domain.com/?id=MYID`

My PHP code:

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
```

And then I'm saving it in JS variable as:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var id = '<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>'; </script>
```

My question is, is it possible to keep the value of `$_SESSION['id']` even when I visit `domain.com` (without the `id` parameter on 2nd visit) with the same browser?

Comment: How long after the first visit are you talking about?

Comment: Light reading [that may be useful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516266/how-long-will-my-session-last)

Comment: @RiggsFolly let's say 24 hours. But is it possible to stick to session_start() without using cookie?

Comment: I coud steal a session of another user this way

Comment: Adding the session identifier to the URL query parameters opens you up to [session hijacking attacks](https://shiflett.org/articles/session-hijacking). This really is a big no-no.

Comment: @Max Muster 

No it's not the session identifier in the URL parameter, it's just a string text that I will grab from the URL. Basically they come to the site from another source with that URL parameter. Now if people remove the URL parameter and visit this page again, I still want the value of the URL parameter saved in their session and pass it through AJAX post to another API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I was defining the `$_SESSION['id']`Even when there is no URL parameter. So, when I visit the page without the URL parameter the `$_SESSION['id']`is still defining it's value with empty/nothing.

So to solve this, I added a `isset` condition to make sure it's only defining when the parameter is posted, otherwise keep the old one.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) { $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id']; }
```